# mod_rewrite does not "pass through" the complete URL when no rules match: Why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

---

**The following question is a red herring: I have tracked the problem down to a bug in a custom routing configuration in my CodeIgniter setup.  The issue has nothing to do with `mod_rewrite`.  Please ignore.**

---

Here is a simplified version of my `mod_rewrite` rules (in the root `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/codeigniter/index.php* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

When I pass the following URL:

```
http://ssilogicserver.webhop.net/codeigniter/index.php/dashboard/index
```

... the URL *seems* to be routed to:

```
http://ssilogicserver.webhop.net/codeigniter/index.php
```

(Note that the final `/dashboard/index` seems to be stripped.)

Here is a snippet of the output of the `mod_rewrite` log:

```
[...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'codeigniter/index.php/dashboard/index'
[...] RewriteCond: input='/codeigniter/index.php/dashboard/index' pattern='!^/codeigniter/index.php*' [NC] => not-matched
[...] pass through L:/daniel347x/__Dan_Root/ssilogicserver_web/ssilogicserver_web/codeigniter/index.php
```

**Note that the URL that is "passed through" is TRUNCATED, even though the rule does not match!**

(Note, also, regarding the third line above, that the document root directory is `L:/daniel347x/__Dan_Root/ssilogicserver_web/ssilogicserver_web/`.  Also note that the above three lines appear contiguously.)

The `.htaccess` file I've posted above is actually just a snippet of the real thing; likewise, the output of the `mod_rewrite` log I've provided is also a snippet.  In my real scenario, I'm actually starting by passing `http://ssilogicserver.webhop.net/codeigniter/index.php` in the browser, and this is first (succesfully, I think) re-routed to `http://ssilogicserver.webhop.net/codeigniter/index.php/dashboard/index` via a `mod_rewrite` rule I haven't listed above; this latter URL is the one in question.

My real problem is a circular redirect.  However, I *think* I have isolated the issue to the lines from the `mod_rewrite` logfile that I've pasted above.  If, in fact, I am not providing enough context in this question - or if it's important that I create a small, independent, reproducible test case along with the **full** `.htaccess` file and the **full** `mod_rewrite` logfile - I will do so (but that will take me a while, so I am starting with this question).

If, in fact, I have properly isolated the relevant details, then my question is: **Why is mod_rewrite "passing through" a truncated URL, even though no `mod_rewrite` rules seem to match**?

(Note: There *is* a file at `codeigniter/index.php`, so perhaps that's related.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/codeigniter/index.php* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

Actually if you look closely rule is doing what it has been told to do do. Your rule says if request URI is not starting with `/codeigniter/index.php` then redirect to `/index.php`.

Since you have `R` flag here therefore it is doing an external redirection to `/index.php` and striping out the current REQUEST_URI in this process..

You probably meant:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/codeigniter/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: But, the `RewriteRule` should never be activated, since the `RewriteCond` does not match, right?

Comment: This .htaccess is in parent directory of `/codeigniter/` right?

Comment: ... adding backslashes made no difference.  Are you certain a backslash is necessary in `index\.php`?

Comment: Oh yes dot means any character in regex so that needs to be escaped all the time. Are you still seeing `/codeigniter/index.php` as the final URL instead of `/codeigniter/index.php/dashboard/index`?

Comment: Also keen to know why do you want to show `domain.com/codeigniter/index.php/dashboard/index` as URL in browser? Should than not be simply: `domain.com/dashboard/index`?

Comment: In fact, in my real `.htaccess` file, I have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` as well, so that only non-existent files match.

Comment: The reason for the ugly URL is that we are en-route to migrating non-CodeIgniter code to CodeIgniter (which lives in a subfolder) (via rewrites in `.htaccess`).  Once the migration is complete, we'll move the CodeIgniter files up to root, remove the ugly rewrites, and return the URL's to normal.

Comment: Note, though, that the `RewriteRule` is **not** being hit... or am I misunderstanding the log?

Comment: See you're entering `/dashboard/index` as your URI and that is not equal to `/codeigniter/index\.php` therefore condition doesn't match (and you can see same message in your rewrite log also).

Comment: The two `.htaccess` lines shown seem to be a red herring.  I have commented them out, and even though no rules match, the URL is still being truncated.

Comment: Since the rule is not actually matching, I guess my question is really "why is the URL being truncated even though no rules match?"  ... I will comment out *every* line in `.htaccess`, test, and modify my question.  Thank you for the time!

Comment: Ok that is probably due to another rule in `/codeignoter/.htaccess` OR some CI routing. Do test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: I tracked down the problem to a custom routing bug in my CodeIgniter configuration.  `mod_rewrite` and the `.htaccess` files have nothing to do with it.  My apologies.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Ah ok no problem at all. I am glad that your problem is resolved.